# openvpn routing in windows vista without admin privileges

Tags: windows, windows-vista, routing, openvpn, permissions

my windows vista vpn client interface receives an ip in: 192.168.50.0/24 
and the server pushes a route to the local lan 192.168.5.0/24

In my windows vista (client) the user account does not have admin privileges and as a consequence the pushed route do not have effect.

A solution I think that would solve the problem is in the openvpn server is using TAP and do a bridge with the lan interface.

is there any other option?

Comment: This works equally well for Windows 7 (64bit). Maybe we can have the question's title changed to reflect that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the user(s) "network operator" privs, this will allow the pushed route to work, but doesn't confer too much extra "power" :)

As far as I know, there's work being done to allow openvpn to run as a priviledged service, which should solve these issues. Not sure where that's got to.
[See this link also](http://openvpn.se/files/howto/openvpn-howto_run_openvpn_as_nonadmin.html)

Comment: How can I  give "network operator" privileges?

Comment: I believe he is suggesting you add the user to the 'Network Configuration Operators" local group.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant - apologies for the lack of clarity.

Comment: I just checked in this windows vista Home (PT) Portuguese version, this group does not exist as a local group. Checked using the 'NET LOCALGROUP' from the command line.

I have upgrade the user permissions for this, or change the operative system to professional version.

Thank you guys.

Comment: Have added a URL to my post which details some further methods. I did presume you would be using XP Pro though.

Answer (score 0):

I did a different thing now.

I connected the server to the vpn network using the open vpn client as a service and now there is need to push this route because its virtual network adapter connects do the vpn and the clients can "talk" to each other.